# Add a dropdown menu to plotly created bar chart using a loop

Tags: function, loops, shiny, plotly, visualization

I want to create a bar graph with plotly that shows the age group on the x axis and the prop on the y axis. Then I want to have a dropdown mwenu that update the figure by reg. My actual data has 20 regions so it will be great to a function with a loop that create the menu automatically. Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075168/loop-plotly-menu)

```
Mdf <- Mdf <- data.frame(age=c(15,20,25,30,35,40,45),cases=c(1200,1110,2233,1445,1323,1510,910),py=c(10101,12465,452424,14240,1544,1574,1154))
Mdf <- rbind(Mdf,Mdf)
Mdf$cases[8:14] <- Mdf$cases[1:7]+3
Mdf$prop <- (Mdf$cases / Mdf$py)*100
Mdf$reg <- c(rep(1,7),rep(2,7))

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
  
  p <- 
    plot_ly(
    y = Mdf$prop,
    x = Mdf$age,
    type = "bar"
  )
```

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Using the function you provided in the link, you get the following

```
Mdf <- Mdf <- data.frame(age=c(15,20,25,30,35,40,45),cases=c(1200,1110,2233,1445,1323,1510,910),py=c(10101,12465,452424,14240,1544,1574,1154))
Mdf <- rbind(Mdf,Mdf)
Mdf$cases[8:14] <- Mdf$cases[1:7]+553
Mdf$prop <- (Mdf$cases / Mdf$py)*100
Mdf$reg <- c(rep("a",7),rep("b",7))

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

p <- Mdf %>% 
  plot_ly(
    y = ~prop,
    x = ~age,
    text = ~reg,
    type = "bar",
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = 'filter',
        target = ~reg,
        operation = '=',
        value = unique(Mdf$reg)[1]
      )
    )) %>% layout(
      updatemenus = get_menu_list(unique(Mdf$reg))
    )
```